# Macbook Pro Early 2015 13" Retina suddenly dead, no response

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have an Early 2015 Macbook Pro retina that was running fine until yesterday. I was watching Netflix on it (running on battery) and it just died without any warning. It has no response at all. When I try the SMC reset, the charging light changes from Orange to Green on releasing the buttons. That is the only response I can coax out of it. It is a lightly used machine with no damage. What could I try before taking it to the Genius Bar?

Comment: Have you tried booting to either internet recovery or Apple Hardware Test?

Comment: There is no boot activity at all on pressing the power key.

Comment: Unfortunately if you can't get a boot there's probably not much we can do to help. The hardware is so locked down on newer models.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if the computer is booting? When you click the home button do you hear the start tone. If you think you had the volume muted, you can do a pram reset which will reset the volume settings, etc..If it boots, to figure out if it’s the physical screen or the system, try plugging the computer in an external monitor or a TV to the HDMI port.